# Why do I get IOError invalid mode ('wb') or filename in cmd but not PowerShell?

Tags: python

When I run this script in cmd (as admin) I get this error. When I run the same script against the same set of files in PowerShell it works fine with no errors. The file it's failing on doesn't have an illegal character.

```
C:\Windows\system32>python D:\Syncback\OurDocs\Darrick\MyPrograms\dbhf.py "C:\Us
ers\Darrick\Dropbox\Camera Uploads" "F:\Pictures\AndroidPics\Auto\"
looking for old files...
2015-06-05 15.33.18.jpg
moving C:\Users\Darrick\Dropbox\Camera Uploads\2015-06-05 15.33.18.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Syncback\OurDocs\Darrick\MyPrograms\dbhf.py", line 29, in <module>
    shutil.move(filepath, destPath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 128, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'F:\\Pictures\\AndroidPics\
\Auto"'
```

The script is pretty simple:

```
dropboxPath = sys.argv[1]
destPath = sys.argv[2]

while True:

    bufferTime = time.time() - 6000

    files = [(f) for f in os.listdir(dropboxPath) for t in filetypes if t in f]
    print 'looking for old files...'
    for fn in files:
        print fn
        filepath = dropboxPath+"\\"+fn

        if os.path.isfile(filepath):
            if os.stat(filepath).st_mtime < bufferTime:
                print "moving "+filepath
                shutil.move(filepath, destPath)

    print "...Going to sleep for 100 minutes now"
    time.sleep(6000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the file's original name after the `destPath`

```
import os.path

dropboxPath = sys.argv[1]
destPath = sys.argv[2]

while True:

    bufferTime = time.time() - 6000

    files = [(f) for f in os.listdir(dropboxPath) for t in filetypes if t in f]
    print 'looking for old files...'
    for fn in files:
        print fn
        filepath = dropboxPath+"\\"+fn

        if os.path.isfile(filepath):
            if os.stat(filepath).st_mtime < bufferTime:
                print "moving "+filepath
                shutil.move(filepath, destPath + fn)

    print "...Going to sleep for 100 minutes now"
    time.sleep(6000)
```

Comment: I am: shutil.move(filepath, destPath + fn). Besides, it works fine in PowerShell.

Comment: In your original post, when you launch the script, you have a ``\`` at the end of the second file path but not the first. Try removing it so that neither have a trailing ``\``. Then try adding a ``\`` to the end of the first file path so that they both have a trailing ``\``.